# Javascript inside templateUrl on ionic popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, popup

I want to make a custom ionic Popup with some images which the user can click in one of them (replacing a usual radiobutton). To do that I will need a javascript to check which image was clicked.
I don't know where to put this javascript code. Inside the html code is not working. Here is the html file referenced by templateUrl:

```
<div class="row">
   <img id="0" src="img/0.png" width="30" height="30" style="opacity:0.5;margin:5px;"/>
   <img id="1" src="img/1.png" width="30" height="30" style="opacity:0.5;margin:5px;"/>
   <img id="2" src="img/2.png" width="30" height="30" style="opacity:0.5;margin:5px;"/>
   <img id="3" src="img/3.png" width="30" height="30" style="opacity:0.5;margin:5px;"/>
   <img id="4" src="img/4.png" width="30" height="30" style="opacity:0.5;margin:5px;"/>
   <img id="5" src="img/5.png" width="30" height="30" style="opacity:0.5;margin:5px;"/>
</div>
Algum Comentário?<br>
<input type="text"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#0').on("click", function(){
    console.log(this);
});
</script>
```

Comment: angular/ionic won't compile script in templates. use custom directive or `ng-click` for this

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is developed in AngularJS, so you should use AngularJS and not jQuery for this.

Here is example how, hopefully you will get idea. Code is in ionic 2 but it is similar for ionic 1 (you didn't wrote which version are you using).

First, in your controller add new method which will be called on image click:

```
imageSelected(index) {
    console.log(index);
}
```

Then use click directive on images inside your template:

```
<div class="row">
   <img src="img/0.png" (click)="imageSelected(1)" />
   <img src="img/1.png" (click)="imageSelected(2)" />
   ...
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your corresponding controller, define resource your template need:

```
$scope.imgIds = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
$scope.onImgClick(imgId) {
  // suit yourself
}
```

And in your template, remove script code:

```
<div class='row'>
  <img ng-repeat='imgId in imgIds' id='imgId' ng-src="img/{{imgId}}.png" ng-click="onImgClick(imgId)" width="30" height="30" style="opacity:0.5;margin:5px;">
</div>
Algum Comentário?<br>
<input type="text"/>
```